# Populate a column based on conditional precedence in Teradata

Tags: teradata, partition, operator-precedence

I need to populate a column based on conditional precedence:

If `O_M` is not zero (eg: `0.34`) , I check the `Prev. record`(which is sequenced by `TP_N`) in the same column `O_M` and if it is zero for 3 or more instances coded with codes `(OD03,OT03,MO03)` then i should populate `To_Compute` column with current `O_M` value - `0.34`. I need to repeat this for every partition (`DT,MNTH,P_ID,A_BR,D_BR,B_BR,DR`) sequenced by `TP_N`. I should only look out for these codes from column `O_N` - `(OD03,OT03,MO03)`

```
DT        MNTH  P_ID    A_BR    D_BR B_BR   TP_N    DR  O_M O_N  TO_Compute
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,006 0   0   ?       0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,007 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,008 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,009 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,010 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,011 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,012 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,013 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,014 0   0   MO03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,015 0   0   OT03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,016 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,017 0   0.34    ?   0.34
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,018 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,019 0   1.03    ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,020 0   0.3     ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,021 0   1.25    ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,022 0   0   OP04    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,023 0   10.53   ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,024 0   0.37    ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,025 0   0.28    ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,026 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,027 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,028 0   0.6     ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,029 0   0.38    ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,030 0   0.4 ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,031 0   0.35    ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,032 0   0.45    ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,033 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,034 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,035 0   0   OD03    0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,036 0   0.3     ?   0.3
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,037 0   0.35    ?   0
9/29/2016   9   QT21    1506    05Y XS-123  487,038 0   0.52    ?   0
```

However, If `O_M` is not zero (eg: `0.6` - 11th row from bottom for column `O_M`) , I check the `Prev. record` in the same column `O_M` and i only have 2 prev records as `zero` ( for 3 or more instances coded with codes `(OD03,OT03,MO03)` then i should populate `To_Compute` column with `0`.

If `O_M` is not zero (eg: `0.3` Third last row for `O_M`) , I check the `Prev. record` in the same column `O_M` and here it is zero for 3 or more instances coded with codes `(OD03,OD03,OD03)` then i should populate `To_Compute` column with current `O_M` value - `0.3`.

I am new to TD. Any light on this could help.

Comment: Do the codes in column O_N have to be in any particular order, and do all three have toe be present?

Comment: If 3 or more prev. consecutive record is zero , then i Check for O_N column, and it has to fall within those three codes. (No nulls). No particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this should work based on your description:

```
case
   when sum(O_M) -- previous three rows are all 0 (assuming no negative values exist)
        over (partition by ??
              order by TP_N
              rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) = 0
    and -- prvious three rows contain any of the searched codes
        sum(case when O_N IN ('OD03','OT03','MO03') then 1 else 0 end)
        over (partition by ??
              order by TP_N
              rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) = 3
   then O_M
   else 0
end
```

Comment: Based on my experience, you can't use a window function within the "when" part of a case statement, but you can use it in the "then" part.

Comment: @M.Wise: When you can use it in THEN you can also use it in WHEN or ELSE :-)

Comment: I confirmed it yesterday.  You get an "Illegal use of Case" error in the WHEN, while running fine in THEN.

Comment: @M.Wise: Well, I do it all the time, this must be something else.Can you share the failing part?

Comment: @dnoeth works perfectly. I am checking for scenarios. however for the question posted - i got the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide two possible solutions for you to decide which works best for your situation.  The first is simpler, but more tedious as it simply joins to the same table 3 times.  Assume your data above exists in the DATASET table:

```
select ds1.dt
,ds1.mnth
,ds1.p_id
,ds1.a_br
,ds1.d_br
,ds1.b_br
,ds1.tp_n
,ds1.dr
,ds1.o_m
,ds1.o_n
,case when zeroifnull(ds4.o_m) + zeroifnull(ds3.o_m) + zeroifnull(ds2.o_m) = 0 and ds4.o_n in ('OD03','OT03','MO03') and ds3.o_n in ('OD03','OT03','MO03') and ds2.o_n in ('OD03','OT03','MO03') then ds1.o_m
else 0 end as TO_COMPUTE
from dataset ds1
left join dataset ds2
on ds1.tp_n = ds2.tp_n +1
and ds1.dt = ds2.dt
and ds1.mnth = ds2.mnth
and ds1.p_id = ds2.p_id
and ds1.a_br = ds2.a_br
and ds1.d_br = ds2.d_br
and ds1.b_br = ds2.b_br
and ds1.dr = ds2.dr
left join dataset ds3
on ds1.tp_n = ds3.tp_n +2
and ds1.dt = ds3.dt
and ds1.mnth = ds3.mnth
and ds1.p_id = ds3.p_id
and ds1.a_br = ds3.a_br
and ds1.d_br = ds3.d_br
and ds1.b_br = ds3.b_br
and ds1.dr = ds3.dr
left join dataset ds4
on ds1.tp_n = ds4.tp_n +3
and ds1.dt = ds4.dt
and ds1.mnth = ds4.mnth
and ds1.p_id = ds4.p_id
and ds1.a_br = ds4.a_br
and ds1.d_br = ds4.d_br
and ds1.b_br = ds4.b_br
and ds1.dr = ds4.dr
order by 7;
```

The second uses partitions within a subquery:

```
select sub.dt
,sub.mnth
,sub.p_id
,sub.a_br
,sub.d_br
,sub.b_br
,sub.tp_n
,sub.dr
,sub.o_m
,sub.o_n
,case when o_m2 = 0 and o_m3 = 0 and o_m4 = 0 and o_n2 in ('OD03','OT03','MO03') and o_n4 in ('OD03','OT03','MO03') and o_n4 in ('OD03','OT03','MO03') then sub.o_m
else 0 end as TO_COMPUTE
from
(
select ds.dt
,ds.mnth
,ds.p_id
,ds.a_br
,ds.d_br
,ds.b_br
,ds.tp_n
,ds.dr
,ds.o_m
,ds.o_n
,max(ds.o_m) over (partition by ds.dt, ds.mnth, ds.p_id, ds.a_br, ds.d_br, ds.b_br, ds.dr order by ds.tp_n rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as O_M2
,max(ds.o_m) over (partition by ds.dt, ds.mnth, ds.p_id, ds.a_br, ds.d_br, ds.b_br, ds.dr order by ds.tp_n rows between 2 preceding and 2 preceding) as O_M3
,max(ds.o_m) over (partition by ds.dt, ds.mnth, ds.p_id, ds.a_br, ds.d_br, ds.b_br, ds.dr order by ds.tp_n rows between 3 preceding and 3 preceding) as O_M4
,max(ds.o_n) over (partition by ds.dt, ds.mnth, ds.p_id, ds.a_br, ds.d_br, ds.b_br, ds.dr order by ds.tp_n rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as O_N2
,max(ds.o_n) over (partition by ds.dt, ds.mnth, ds.p_id, ds.a_br, ds.d_br, ds.b_br, ds.dr order by ds.tp_n rows between 2 preceding and 2 preceding) as O_N3
,max(ds.o_n) over (partition by ds.dt, ds.mnth, ds.p_id, ds.a_br, ds.d_br, ds.b_br, ds.dr order by ds.tp_n rows between 3 preceding and 3 preceding) as O_N4
from dataset ds
) sub
order by 7;
```